# MODIS MOD11A1 Reproject Change Data Value

Tags: qgis, gdal, modis

I'm import and reprojected MOD11A1 with GDAL 1.10....my shell script is easy..

```
for file in *.hdf; do
echo "map: $file"

gdal_translate -of Gtiff -ot Int16 HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"$file":MODIS_Grid_Daily_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km  -a_nodata -9999 out/${file}.tif
echo "out/"${file}".tif" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";}{ print "mv "$0" "$1"."$2"."$3"."$4"."$5"."$7}' |sh`
```

but when running script reprojected 
something is wrong with data...

```
for file in *.tif; do
echo "map: $file"


gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:32719 \
    -te 333524.4980000000214204 6618581.1791345691308379 422017.2268572300090455 6679275.1449999995529652 -tr 926.625 -926.625 \
    -dstnodata -9999 -ot Int16 $file utm/${file}

done
```

look my screenshot on qgis....[image: sript 1 import hdf]

[image: script 2 reprojected tif]

any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok My Solution .... write next scrip for scaling data Land Surface Temperature MOD11A1.....

```
for file in *.tif; do
echo "map: $file"
gdal_calc.py -A $file --outfile=sc/$file  --calc=A*0.02

done
```

Nice!!!!!!! Linux is wonderful specially if you want more 5500 images...

Thanks a Lot  AndreJ... for you comments

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the files metadata, the modis source data has a scale factor of 0.02. QGIS applies it on-the-fly.

But the reprojection with gdalwarp destroys the scale factor information, hence the result is unscaled. You have to apply it manually to get the correct results.

Comment: Thanks a lot AndreJ... thats right gdalwarp destroy factor scale data of 0.02 now working in a Shell Script for multiply 5000 img...any idea...