# Changing of pixel values when clipping raster by mask in QGIS

Tags: raster, clip

I am using '[Clip raster by mask layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#clip-raster-by-mask-layer)' in QGIS to clip a raster temperature layer down to the size of the area I'm interested in using a polygon. The resulting clipped layer is a raster that has pixel values significantly different from the original.

I am doing this same process with different raster layers and it usually works fine, but some clipped layers come out with pixel values totally off. This is not an issue of values display. It's just that the pixels have different values. For example, when I right-click with 'identifier features' option on a random pixel it gives me values of 26.95 in the original (which makes complete sense as this is the value of mean annual temperature) and a value of 3001 in the clipped raster.

[image]

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

---

I couldn't attach the image in my previous comment. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Does your clipped raster have the same bit depth as the original? It may be that the clipped raster is of integer type and cannot store floating point values.

Comment: I agree with @Matt, you can start by comparing the pixel depth and nodata values of the input and outputs

Comment: If the issue was data type then would the result be 11 in the example provided?

Comment: 8-bit range is 0-255 and 16-bit range is 0-65535. `65536/2844=23.04` and `256/11=23.27`. Thus about the same proportion of the full scale. You may have changed the datatype. Another option is that the original image is of higher bit depth but it has scale and offset stored into the image metadata and QGIS know to make the conversion into temperature units. I do not know if it can do that. You should add gdalinfo reports about your images.

Comment: Thanks so much for your expert replies. I think you're all right. I've checked and seems that the datatype have changed. The clipped raster is 64-bit and the original one is 32-bit. Also, there is indeed scale and offset embedded into the original image. Could you tell me what these are? So now I know what may be wrong but I still don't know how to fix it. Is there a way to clip the rasters in a way that they keep the same datatype? Many thanks.

Comment: Part of Gdal report: 

{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'D:/Chelsa/Present/CHELSA_bio1_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : True, 'MASK' : 'C:\\Users\\mcgallego\\Documents\\ETHIOPIA\\QGIS\\EthiopiaMask.shp', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : -999999999, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : None, 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }

Warning 1: for band 1, destination nodata value has been clamped to 0, the original value being out of range.

Comment: With gdalinfo report I meant the report that this utility creates https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html. I could not find reference for scale and offset. This is what they do: if you have a pixel with value 2000, offset 1000 and scale 0.001, then first add the offset (2000+1000=3000) and then multiply with the scale (3000*0.001=3). So pixel value 2000 means measurement value 3. I hope I got the signs correctly but compare with https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229719/gdalwarp-change-pixel-value. See also `-unscale` in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html and experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you run the mask tool, use the GDAL Translate (convert format) tool to unscale your input raster as follows:

1. Select tool from toolbox under GDAL->Raster conversion -> Translate
2. Choose your input raster as the input layer for the translate tool
3. Type -unscale -co DECIMAL_PRECISION=2 in the Additional command-line parameters (don't forget the leading hyphen)
4. Choose output filename and location
5. Run the Translate tool and use the output (unscaled tiff) as the input to 'clip raster from mask' as you did before.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that, but that doesn't solve the issue. The pixel values in the clipped raster are still different from the original raster.

Comment: OK thanks, can you pull up the properties of your input data (right click -> properties)  then click the information tab on the left menu and tell me what you see under "Information from Provider -> data type" ?

Comment: It says: "Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point".

Comment: can you try adding -unscale in the blank directly below the one circled in red above? The one labeled "additional command-line parameters [optional]".

Comment: It gives the following error: 
ERROR 4: unscale: No such file or directory

Comment: OK cool, that was because gdalwarp doesn't accept -unscale as a parameter, so you need to use gdaltranslate first. I edited my answer to reflect this, can you try it now?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. It works perfectly fine. I don't want to abuse of your knowledge but if I may ask one last question regarding this. Everything looks ok now but the pixel values in the new clipped layer have been rounded, so where there was, for example, 12.95 °C in the original, it has changed to 13 °C in the clipped raster (please see captured image). Is there a way to keep the two decimals in the pixel values. Many thanks again.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I changed the answer once again, this time to include the decimal precision in the gdal translate call. If this answer is satisfactory, please accept as correct.